# call one functional componet to anther functinal component in react js

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have created one functional component that name is TopLocation() and i am calling this function to another component  const handleChange = e => {
TopLocation(e.target.value)
}

```
function TopLocation (cityid=null) {
     const[location,setLocation]=useState();
     let city={city_id:(cityid==''?localStorage.getItem("location"):cityid)};
     useEffect(()=> {
      const  fetchData= async()=>{
        const result = await Locationapi(
          city
        );
        console.log('result',result);
        if(result.status==200){
          setLocation(result.data);
        }
      }
      fetchData();
    },[]);
```

it's showing error.
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Answer (score 0):

**Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions**

but you can call react hooks inside of your own custom hook

read more about hooks over here

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html